# Map of map insert returning incorrect answer

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, find

I am using a map inside of a map to track some data.

In order to add some data, I first check to see if I am tracking based on a global key as a string.

If I have that key in my map, I then check a map inside of that first map to see if it has a value, with a key as an unsigned short int. Here is the structure.

```
map<string, fileInfo> fileMap;

class fileInfo {
public:
    unsigned short int numNeighbors;
    map<unsigned short int, neighborInfo> neighbors; //key is id
//... more
}
```

I am able to to check if my primary key is in my overall map, but when I check to see if that key is in there, I am getting a false on inserting, indicating this neighbor already exists, but it doesn't. I have sanity checked and made sure to see if my keys match, and they do not.

finding first key

```
it = fileMap.find(filename);
if (it == fileMap.end()) {
//add to fileMap
}else{
    fileInfo currFI = it->second;
    neighborInfo n = createNeighbor();
    pair<it_Neighbor, bool> ret;
    map<unsigned short int, neighborInfo> neighbors = currFI.neighbors;
    ret = currFI.neighbors.insert(pair<unsigned short int, neighborInfo> (id, n));
    if (ret.second == false) {
            cout<< "Neighbor already exists for this file, ignoring duplicates."<< endl;

    } else {   
            cout << "size" << currFI.neighbors.size() << endl;
}
```

my size output is always 2, when it should be 4.

Do I need to define any operators or anything in my classes in order to make this work?

Comment: How do you check if a key exists?

Comment: You should *really* also post the accessing code.

Comment: Gold badges, 1000+ rep and 1+ year member, you should know better...

Comment: upadted. I understand this maybe second nature to a c guru, but I am not as familiar with it.

Comment: `currFI` is discarded when the `else` block ends, changes never make it to the `fileMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
fileInfo currFI = it->second;
```

try

```
fileInfo &currFI = it->second;
```

The `currFI` variable is discarded when the else block end. You should make it a `reference` to the `fileMap` item, so it is preserved there.